# ASP.NET - Source control tool for .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, version-control

I am going to develop my first application (4 members team).I am not aware of source control tool ( Visual

source safe,Tortoise SVN).

My .NET version is 3.5. What is the best source control tool ?

Is CruiseControl  a source control tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pure Windows environment then [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is a Windows version of SVN server and installs easily and cleanly. You can setup security using Windows usernames and passwords, or SVN usernames and passwords.

You can then use [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to provide integration in Explorer and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) to provide Visual Studio integration (there's a small cost for VisualSVN) or you could try [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) if all you want is VS integration and don't want to spend any money. Personally I prefer VisualSVN's integration.

Running a GIT server under Windows is, umm, frankly a pain in the ass, and not a route I'd recommend for beginners. VS integration is also fraught with pain.

As with everyone else I'd say avoid SourceSafe like the plague.

CruiseControl is not a source control system, it's an automated build server. It monitors source control servers looking for changes, then checks everything out, compiles it and runs it through your unit tests, so people know if they've broken the build. Once you have source control up and running it's the next big step towards a better build environment.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely avoid Visual Source Safe.

Subversion is probably a safe choice, but you will have to elaborate about your situation (E.g. how big is your team?) to get more specific advice.

Comment: Just 4 members in my team.We are developing utility tool in .NET to server banking domain.

Answer (score 4):

Another no vote for Visual Source Safe here.

Might be an idea to get familiar with subversion as - just as others mentioned - it's widely adopted, so might be useful in the future and simply works..oh and it's free too!
TortoiseSVN integrates into the windows explorer and is both easy to use and well documented so I would give it a try.

If it's a small project of yours and you don't want to worry about hosting, I would recommend signing up for a free account at something like beanstalk, to keep it safe, without any hassle.

But if it's your first ever project, it might just give you too many additional things to learn about, so you might want to put it aside for a while.

Answer (score 3):

*(quated part is no more important since you edited your post about team size)*

> If you are doing some small project on
>   your own, maybe you shouldn't use code
>   versioning at all because you probably
>   don't need it. Code versioning helps
>   you with central code storage,
>   multi-person development code merging
>   (several people working on the same
>   file and then commit changes) and code
>   branching to name the most important
>   ones.
>
> If I were you, and I would be the only
>   person developing something simple, I
>   wouldn't use it, because it would also
>   be a bit of a time-overkill.

But otherwise source control doesn't address technology like .Net framework version. Code control only stores files (with history) and is able to merge text files. Written in whatever language possible.

If you are part of a team I'd suggest using **Subversion + TortoiseSVN + AnkhSVN**

And **No, CruiseControl is not** a code versioning system. It's a [**continuous integration system**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Comment: Thanks robert for detailed expln

Comment: No worries. We are here to help anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try GIT, it's much lighter weight than svn

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/

you can use a local repository for just checking in your own work (to keep a history, or to keep a working version before changing everything) Or you can connect to a central repository for enterprise source control.

The company where I work used to use the SVN, Tortoise, Ankh stack but we're using Git now. Plus I use it at home on my on play projects.

Answer (score 2):

Before we start talking about source control, I would like you to consider your actual *need* for it, if this is to be your first .NET application. Is this your *actual first attempt of writing some .NET 3.5 code*? If so, I doubt that you need to worry about source control just yet. I would say it's not just a little bit overkill for the first learning projects.
On the other hand, if this is to be your first application that you'll actually *sell* to someone, it's a completely different matter.

I currently use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/), an add-in to Visual Studio that lets you do check-in, check-out etc from within the environment. Along with it, I use the free SVN repository service at [XP-Dev](http://www.xp-dev.com/). It works well for me =)

Comment: Yes I am new to programming.This is my first development project in .NET.

Comment: Then I would recommend not worrying about source control just yet. Start up VS (or one of the Express editions) and get a feel for the IDE, the language and the .NET Framework. If you're intrested in going towards the web, take a look at http://www.asp.net/learn and http://www.asp.net/videos for a nice set of startup tutorials. When you're actually going to develop something that you want to use live or sell, then it's time for source control worrying. Until then, just have fun! =)

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of a versioning system does not have to do anything with the .NET version you are using.

I'd vote for Subversion / Tortoise SVN. It's rock-solid, has lots of handy features, widely adopted and free.